# TIdHTTP hanging on network disconnect

Tags: delphi, indy10

I'm sending large chunks of data to our servers using TIdHTTP Post. The uploads work great, but on network disconnect and then reconnect, I need to continue where I left off. This all works fine some of the time, but what happens on network disconnect is that the current chunk hangs. The Post request never returns.

It's imperative that I do not give up on the upload. Uploads must complete eventually. The software runs on regular user's PCs, so I have no control over their network topology or stability.

So, how can I make sure the Post request fails on network disconnect, rather than hangs indefinitely?

I don't have the patience to see if it will "eventually fail". I've waited quite a while several times, but it hasn't returned. Moreover, even if it does eventually fail, it's too long. I need this to fail quickly so I can regain control over the scheduling.

Is there some way to force a timeout and have it actually work? The debugger shows it's hanging in FDSelect on a IOHandler.ReadLn.

My Indy version is 10.5.5, and this isn't easily changed either...

Comment: Maybe show the relevant client side and server side code? AFAIK Readln has a timeout parameter...

Comment: I solved it by recreating the IdHTTP object. The object gets corrupted somehow after one bad call, and it's actually the next one that has the issue. I don't know why it has an issue, and I don't care, since I can recreate the http object when I get any exception and have it work. I lose keep-alive when there's errors, but oh well...